# Dropbox:How to hide application data using Sync API

Tags: synchronization, dropbox, dropbox-api

Am using dropbox [Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync) to sync application data with Dropbox. Using this SDK creates a new folder with application name inside 'Apps' folder. Both folder and files inside application data folder are visible to user through web browser interface. I intended to hide application data files from user. Please let me know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to hide files in a user's Dropbox.  However you may want to check out the new Datastores API (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore).  That's designed for app data/settings, and doesn't show up as files in the user's Dropbox.  Users can get access to datastores via the Datastore Explorer on the web, though, so it's not entirely hidden, but it's not in the user's face or easily editable by a user either.

Comment: This link doesn't work

Comment: https://dropbox.tech/developers/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has no notion of "hidden" files, so this isn't possible.